# How to Get the Accuracy of significant Location update in iphone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, location

How can one know of the accuracy level of the significant location update in iphone?? As the standard location, one can set the accuracy level depending upon the parameters that can be set, but whereas the significant location accuracy cannot be set for accuracy but how to read the accuracy of the received location update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class `CLLocationManager` has an accuracy parameter, called `desiredAccuracy` which is of the class `CLLocationAccuracy`. But hold up! Its not a class, its a `typedef double` so here are the constants

```
extern const CLLocationAccuracy kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_10_7,__IPHONE_4_0);
extern const CLLocationAccuracy kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
extern const CLLocationAccuracy kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters;
extern const CLLocationAccuracy kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters;
extern const CLLocationAccuracy kCLLocationAccuracyKilometer;
extern const CLLocationAccuracy kCLLocationAccuracyThreeKilometers;
```

What I suggest you do is assign your location manager's accuracy to a new variable it and compare it like the following:

```
CLLocationAccuracy locationAccuracy = self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy;

if (locationAccuracy == kCLLocationAccuracyBest) {

    NSLog(@"It is the kCLLocationAccuracyBest my life is complete!");
}
else if (/*other comparisons stuff here*/) {

}
```

Also, you have to import:

```
#import <CoreLocation/CLLocation.h>
```

Rohan

Comment: is there any other method to get the exact values that is some quantifiable terms like say 200m in any case?

Comment: @raghul Im sorry I do not understand what you mean

Comment: I found out that there is a parameter called horizontalaccuracy which can be used to get the accuracy, and there are much more location like speed,altitude, vertical accuracy